# Consume WCF SOAP web services from ASP.NET MVC Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, soap, middleware

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.

I need to consume a WCF SOAP service from that Web API and I'm wondering if it is a good idea.
Maybe I can use Windows Service to consume that WCF SOAP service or another kind of middleware to help another programs (Windows Form) consume that WCF SOAP.

Do may I use ASP.NET Web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to consume WCF through web api , its perfectly fine. You will need to map wcf data contracts with your web api models.

*Maybe I can use Windows Service to consume that WCF SOAP service or another kind of middleware to help another programs (Windows Form) consume that WCF SOAP*

SOAP is standard and can be consumed by any client. If your api needs data from wcf there is no point is putting it in Windows Service/Winform.

To see example of WCF with Web Api [check this out.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d13d20/creating-aspnet-mvc-app-with-wcf-service-docx/)